# NSMutableString defining and redefining

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I am at a loss as hot to properly initiate a NSMutableString, I have tried:

```
NSMutableString *string = @"some text";
```

which is the same method one assigns a string to an NSString but have hade no luck. Additionally I have not been able to figure out how to redefine the string contained with the NSMutableString. I would imagine it would look something like:

```
string = @"new text";
```

Any help and code on this basic subject would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"some text"];
```

Your examples are just making `string` point to a constant string, which is bad news, probably.  To set the string, use:

```
[string setString:@"new text"];
```

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunatly i tryed the following code an the compiler gives me the error: 
initializer element is not constant
on the line:
NSMutableString *url_of_server=[NSMutableStringstringWithFormat:@"http://111.111.1.1:80/file"];

Any ideas?

Comment: @jcb344 you can't have a method invocation in a global variable declaration.  If you need a global `NSMutableString`, set it up in your `awakeFromNib` or something.